# AppCompatV7 newest version for API 10

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I'm going to develop an android APP with min API = 10.
Currently my build tools offer `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1` which its min API level is equal to 14.
Which is the newest release for `appcompat-v7` which can run on my old API 10?
I could not find a suitable reference for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/#api-versions):

> Support Library packages have package names to indicate the minimum
>   level of the API they originally supported, using a v# notation, such
>   as the support-v4 package. **Starting with Support Library version
>   26.0.0 (released in July 2017)**, the **minimum supported API level has changed to Android 4.0 (API level 14)** for all support library
>   packages.
>
> **The support-v4 and the support-v7 package both support a minimum API level of 14, for releases of the Support Library from 26.0.0 and higher**

You need to version prior to `26.0.0` use `25.4.0`. You can refer to the exhaustive list of versions [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions).

**Do take note of following point:**

> The release version level of the support library indicates it
>   incorporates some features of that API level, **but you should not
>   assume it provides compatibility with all features released in the new
>   platform API version.**

Answer (score 1):

The minimum SDK for the support libraries [was raised to 14 with `26.0.0`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions#important-changes_10).

The highest version prior to that change is [`25.4.0`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/rev-archive#25-4-0).

Answer (score 1):

Revision 26.0.0 Release
(July 2017)

> Caution: Starting with Support Library release 26.0.0 (July 2017), the
>   minimum supported API level across most support libraries has
>   increased to Android 4.0 (API level 14) for most library packages. For
>   more information, see Version Support and Package Names in this
>   document.

Hence you should use below 26.0.0 to achieve what you want.Thanks!